# Kendo UI Grid - how to increase performance when loading large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, kendo-grid, progress-4gl

I have a large dataset with around 1000 records. When I load the data with Kendo Grid it takes too long. I don't want to use paging or virtual scrolling. Should it take so long? Is there a way to load the data instantaneously? Its just plain text data so I don't understand why it takes so long. When I run it in chrome and check the network tab it seems to be taking long with the jquery.min.js file. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Add more information. HOW do you load the data for instance? Do you really need to load all 1000 records?

Comment: Its a kendo datasource linked to Progress backend. The data is fetched as a JSON object and then the response is an object with the record.I would want to see 1000 records load fast.

Comment: Can you run only the query on server side and check the time? It will never be faster than that! Server side paging is something for you to look into.

Comment: Yes on the server side the query is fast and results shown instantly. So you think the only way round is to fetch bits if data either by using paging or possibly virtual scrolling? Thank you for your comment

Comment: I don't know about kendo grids but in general I would say loading that big amount of data without filtering or paging seems strange. Why would you want/need all those records loaded?

Comment: Well, with Kendo grids you can do inline editing, so when changing a record you would want to have them all displayed in a list and just scroll down rather than changing a few then clicking on the next page then editing the others. If all data is loaded at once quickly then all editing can me made easily and one button click action can process is all. So reduces the number of mouse clicks. Just trying to make it easier for the user really. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

Comment: How long is "too long"?  What measurement would you consider to be "fast"?  "It is just plain text"... 1000 records of what average length?  How large is the JSON result set?  What sort of network is between your server and client?  How fast can it transfer the amount of data that you are working with?  If the network cannot transfer the data fast enough to meet your criteria then you will need to approach the problem differently if it *is* capable but you do not see the desired result then perhaps it is a coding issue.  Right now you have not provided enough background info to distinguish.

Comment: Hey, it was in fact a coding issue. For my server side coding I was using Progress code and I combined a few conditions within a query in a messy way which made it slow. I just separated each condition within the query (longer code to write) but it solved the issue. Thanks though.